# Smiley parser and xss injection protection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to make a simple chat, and, at the beginning, just parse ':)' and add an image before appending the message.
Here's what I tried :

```
var string = "The message the user wrote";
var message = $('<div class=\"chat-message\"></div>').text(string);            
message.html(message.text().replace(':)', '<img src="smile.png"/>')).appendTo('#chat-messages');
```

Okey, it's works, but let's imagine someone sends this :

```
<img src="Some illicite picture"/>
```

Well, it would just display the picture, and I don't want the users to inject HTML code in the page.

So, how can I do ?

Comment: What about enclosing all chat content with `<pre>` or `<code>` blocks unless explicitly matched and replaced with HTML by you?

Comment: wont `message.text()` strip that out?

Comment: Actually, since you are already using jQuery, consider @Adween suggestion of using `message.text()`.  It is similar to calling `document.createTextNode()` which is a native way of doing escaping.  Consider this article: [**HTML escaping in Javascript**](http://shebang.brandonmintern.com/foolproof-html-escaping-in-javascript/)

Comment: @zero298 it is already calling `text()` Here: `message.text().replace(':)', '<img src="smile.png"/>')` this will strip all html and just get the text, then replace the smiley `:)` with the html for the image

Comment: Well I tried the text() alternative, but using message.html() replace the escaped text with html.. I just want the <img src="smile.png"/> to be interpreted as HTML and only keep the message escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the HTML chars at Serverside, because Javascript could be bypassed.
In PHP this is done by the htmlspecialchars function, so:
`$newText = htmlspecialchars($oldtext);`

Comment: Well, I coded the server myself in C++, it's a websocket server, I made my own implementation. So.. the client is in pure HTML/JS

Comment: Well then escape it with C++(replace < and > by &lt; &gt; should do it) and replace the smilies on clientside with js.